# The confusion about the split() function of JavaScript with an empty string

Tags: javascript, split

First I set a variable, and set it to empty:

```
var str = "";
```

Then I split it through "&":

```
var strs = str.split('&');
```

In the end, I show `strs`'s length:

```
alert( strs.length);
```

It alert "1".

But I assign nothing to the 'str' variable. Why does it still have a length, should't it be zero?

Comment: you could do a simple `.split('...').filter(Boolean)`  if you didnt care about falsy values.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

From the MDC doc center:

> Note: When the string is empty, `split` returns an array containing one empty string, rather than an empty array.

Read the full docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

In other words, this is by design, and not an error :)

Comment: When would this 'design choice' be better than returning an empty array?

Comment: It's for consistency. `'&'.split('&')` returns 2 empty strings; `'&&'.split('&')` returns 3; etc.

Comment: @Spongman it is not an error, it makes perfect sense. If it worked any other way it would be inconsistent, and inconsistency is arguably the worst sin in programming.

Comment: Let's think about this by example. Imagine you have a text file with three lines and you splitting it at newlines: `"One\n\nThree".split('\n')` which is `["One","","Three"]`. Notice that the second line is blank (`""`). If the text file has only one line, `"One".split('\n')` the result is `["One"]`. So logically, `"".split('\n')` should be `[""]` since there is still one line. The line is blank, but we saw before that a blank line is `""`. In some languages such as C# there is an option to remove empty entries from the output, but JavaScript does not offer it.

Comment: You could try `str.split('&').filter(o=>o)` which would eliminate any empty string in the array and in your case, it would return an empty array!

Comment: This is an old thread, but I agree with @hh54188 and @Steve Eynon--this is precisely **inconsistent**.  Consider @Jonathan Lidbeck's examples:
`["", "", ""].join( "&" ).split( "&" )
--> ["", "", ""]` (consistent), `["", ""].join( "&" ).split( "&" ) --> ["", ""]` (consistent), and `[""].join( "&" ).split( "&" ) --> [""]` (consistent), but `[].join( "&" ).split( "&" ) --> [""]` (**inconsistent**)!

Comment: @MarkMYoung - your logic is flawed. The split function is 100% consistent. Your example simply highlights that array joins work in ways you find inconsistent, not that string splitting does. [].join and [""].join are the same thing due to type coercion, which, like it or not, is a defining feature of the javascript language.

Comment: @MartinJespersen, no, my logic is mathematical.  "Let d ∈ String, sᵢ ∈ String, and a ∈ { String } such that split( d, sᵢ ) = a, where ā = count of d in sᵢ and such that join( d, a ) = sᵢ where count of d in sᵢ = ā."  However, JavaScript throws in "for all values of i > 1".

Comment: @MArkMYoung sadly you are missing the point - this question is about the split function. You are focusing on the join function.Your observation is correct, yet completely irrelevant to the post.

Comment: @MartinJespersen, I was offering the interpretation of "consistency" of @hh54188, @Steve Enyon, mathematics, and the OP which makes it totally relevant to the question.  I understand what you're saying though and I understand that the specification of `split` is basically to "return an array of length one greater than the number of separators in the string" (the definition of `limit` in the specification breaks this) in an attempt to be "consistent" with string manipulation, which is where ECMAScript was born.  Regards

Answer (score 9):

**Splitting window.location.pathname**

Note that on window.location.pathname splitting it will mostly return a length of +1 also.

Lets assume our pathname in this case is: `/index.html`.

```
var str = window.location.pathname.split('/');
```

It will be split into `["" , "index.html"]` by design, as mentioned here many times before.

What one could do in this case is, strip the leading and trailing `/` like so:

```
var str = window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '').split('/');
```

and end up with the "correct"ed length.

Answer (score 8):

Because you get an array that contains the empty string:

```
[ "" ]
```

That empty string is one element. So `length` is 1.

Answer (score 7):

Eliminate any null string.

```js
str.split('{SEPERATOR}').filter(r => r !== 'null')
```

Comment: That seems to be checking for a string that has a value of 'null'. This works> .filter(r => r !== '')

Answer (score 4):

> Description
>
> The split method returns the new
>   array.
>
> When found, separator is removed from
>   the string and the substrings are
>   returned in an array. If separator is
>   omitted, the array contains one
>   element consisting of the entire
>   string.
>
> **Note: When the string is empty, split returns an array containing one
>   empty string, rather than an empty
>   array.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 2):

I got sick of always checking for a[0] == '' so:

```
String.prototype.splitPlus = function(sep) {
  var a = this.split(sep)
  if (a[0] == '') return [];
  return a;
};
```

**Corrected version for when element 1 might be null:**

```
 String.prototype.splitPlus = function(sep) {
   var a = this.split(sep)
   if (a[0] == '' && a.length == 1) return [];
   return a;
  };
```

Comment: This will fail for ",a,b,c".splitPlus(","), though - returning [] when it should return ["", "a", "b", "c"]. You have to check for the array length as well.

Comment: add && a.length > 0 to your if condition.

Comment: @aggaton I added the corrected version with : `if (a[0] == '' && a.length == 1) return [];`

Comment: why not `===`? .

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript `split` creates an array. That is, your variable, `strs = [0]=>""` and its length is 1.

Answer (score 0):

invent **explode**/implode (like PHP)

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype,"explode",{
    value: function (sep = '') {
        return this.length ? this.split(sep) : [];
    }
});
```

so empty-string goes to empty-array

Answer (score -1):

try this

javascript gives two arrays by split function, then

```
var Val = "abc@gmail.com";
var mail = Val.split('@');

if(mail[0] && mail[1])  {   alert('valid'); }
else    {   alert('Enter valid email id');  valid=0;    }
```

if both array contains length greater than 0 then condition will true